# R - use Dplyr mutate with Purrr for string manipulation

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr, grepl

I have two tibbles with list of strings in each. I need to compare one list of strings with another list of strings and depending on the comparison create a new column.

Small example below:

```
## Tibble 1 - the 'master' 
structure(list(terms = c("This", "is", "a", "stri", "of", "areas", 
"times", "two", "to", "see", "what", "will", "be", "in", "the", 
"magic", "will", "rally", "for", "a", "cry", "from", "the", "deepest", 
"part", "of", "the", "ocean", "com", "en", "au", "us"), rank = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", 
"L", "M", "N", "O", "P"), id = 1:32), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

## Tibble 2 - the 'comparison' 

structure(list(conds = c("this.com", "two.org", "magic.edu", 
"cry/en/org", "magic.com"), ind = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("bad", "good", "Indifferent", "Maybe", "Ugly"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ideally the output would be a mutated 'master' tibble with the ind value inserted depending on the comparison of the strings

Attempt so far:

```
terms <- terms %>% mutate(
  test = ifelse(
    sapply(lapply(terms, grepl, condition_str$conds), any) == TRUE, 
        condition_str$ind, 
        'NA'))

terms
```

result

```
 # A tibble: 32 x 4
   terms rank     id test 
   <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>
 1 This  A         1 NA   
 2 is    B         2 1    
 3 a     C         3 5    
 4 stri  D         4 NA   
 5 of    E         5 NA   
 6 areas F         6 NA   
 7 times G         7 NA   
 8 two   H         8 5    
 9 to    I         9 NA   
10 see   J        10 NA
```

It gives me a result, the factor levels are carried across but the factor names are not. It fails on a larger data set I am working on.

Questions:

- Is there a purrr solution that uses stringr or stringi? My problem might be in my string matching
- Is there a way to use incorporate `fixed = TRUE` into the grepl function?
- Is there a way to get the classification levels into the mutated column?

Thanks for any assistance.

James

Comment: what exactly is the logic of creating test?

Comment: To classify each of the observations based on the contents of the string in the main df. thx

Comment: but youve got 2, 3 etc. How is that a classification. ie could you explain as to why  This->NA, is-> 2, a->3??